# why does the minBy() returns Optional but others dont?

Tags: java, stream

My question is why the Collectors.minBy () method returns an **Optional**, but the Collectors.summingInt () or Collectors.averagingInt () method does not return an Optional? Is it not possible that the stream is empty when these methods are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, you cannot have a minimum or maximum if the collection is empty. Returning an empty `Optional` is appropriate when no legitimate value is possible.

In contrast, one could argue that a sum of no elements (empty collection) is zero, zero meaning “nothing” numerically. If I have no apples, and I add to that an empty bag of no apples, how many apples do I have? Zero; the sum of nothing is zero.

Ditto for average. If I have three empty bags, the average count of apples per bag is zero.

However, I acknowledge that reasonable people could disagree, especially in certain contexts. I do not know what a mathematician world say. But I do believe the common businessperson would  expect zero in both cases.

Note that the Javadoc clearly states: “If no elements are present, the result is 0.”. **In the end, all that matters is what behavior the Javadoc promises.** If that behavior does not match your expectations, replace your use of that class with another class that does, or write your own.

Comment: I agree that the *sum* of an empty collection is zero, but why would its *average* be zero (as opposed to any other value)?

Comment: @ruakh That is why I used the phrase “one could argue” — *reasonable people could disagree* about an average or sum of nothing being zero. I don’t know what a mathematician would say. I would guess that a common businessperson would consider zero appropriate. In the end, all that matters is what the Javadoc tells us to expect. If that behavior does not match your expectations, replace your use of that class with another class that does, or write your own.

Comment: But how do you know that "one could argue" this, if you can't think of any arguments at all that one could make for it? (And why would you answer a question about "why" if you can't actually think of a reason why?)

Comment: @ruakh As noted in my Answer, the meaning of zero is nothing. If I have no apples, and I add to that a empty bag of no apples, how many apples do I have? Zero; the sum of nothing is zero. That is my reason. And I am beginning to see why questions on “Why did the authors of class *X* choose…?” are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The three empty bags example is not analogous to the average of an empty list.  It is analogous to the average of a list containing three zeroes.  An average is the sum of the elements divided by the number of elements.  For an empty list, accepting the sum of elements to be zero, that is 0 / 0, which is mathematically undefined.  I think reporting 0 for this case is simply a poor choice in the design of the class, now immortalized for the sake of compatibility.